# How to write match in route.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my AdminController, I have methods named as edit, update and update_admin. And  in route.rb

```
  resources :session, :only => [update]
    match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
  end
```

When I navigate the url '/users/edit/1' matches. From this page i want to call the action method in update_admin in AdminController. How to do this?

My edit.erb has

```
    <%= render :partial => '/submit', :locals =
> {:button_html => f.submit('Update'), :validate_present => true}
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

at first, to check your routes go to console and do

```
rake routes | grep session
```

there you will get list all routes of your rails application (matched to the grep)

at second i dont get your routes.rb

would you do

```
resources :session, :only => [update] do
  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
end
```

or

```
  resources :session, :only => [update]
  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
end
```

these are 2 different things. i think you want the last one. but here we go, there is another problem

```
resources :session, :only=>[update]
```

this throws an error.(undefined local variable or method `update' for #)
if you want to specify actions, you need to do it as a key

```
resources :session, :only=>[:update]
```

but you also want the edit message, (edit is the form, update the action to save the changes) so you have to do

```
resources :users, :only=>[:edit, :update]
```

now check your rake routes and see voila!

```
                   edit_session GET        /session/:id/edit(.:format)                {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"session"}
                    session PUT        /session/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"session"}
```

**//edit**

if you want to do this in your admin_controller you should have a namespace

```
#i take example for a user
namespace :admin do
  resources :user :only => [:edit, :update]
end
```

if you want now to link to it from a view the route is named
    edit_admin_user_path

and in a form you need to bring the namespace also in the form_for like:

```
=form_for [:admin, @user] do |f|
```